# Views can be used to provide a backward compatible interface

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

> Views can be used to provide a backward compatible interface to
> emulate a table that used to exist but whose schema has changed.

[Sql Server - Database Design - Views](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/views?view=sql-server-ver15)

What does that mean, can somebody explain?

Is it saying, when there is a change in the schema of tables that are used in creating views, doesn't alter the view?

Comment: 'when there is a change in the schema of tables that are used in creating views, doesn't alter the view' - correct you have to be careful when changing table schemas that you don't break views. for exampl IF a view selects column a from table1 and you split table1 so that column a now lives in table2 then your view is broken. But you can amend the view so that the end user doesn't notice the split.

Comment: You may provide more background information related to that statement, like where did you saw this statement, and format your guess. This can make your question better and others can give your more precise answer or example.

Answer (score 3):

One of the big problems in working with databases is handling changes over time.  The issue is that downstream users depend on the data model they are using.

You can isolate downstream users by having them rely on views, rather than directly accessing the base tables.

For instance, you might start with a table that has a user table with an `address` column.  Folks downstream access the table as:

```
select u.*
from users u;
```

Later, you realize that addresses can change and you want to implement a type-2 table for addresses -- that is, a separate table with an effective and end date on each record.  Well, existing code will break.

Instead, if the downstream users are using:

```
select u.*
from v_users u;
```

Then the view only needs to change from:

```
create view v_users as
    select u.user_id, u.address
    from users u;
```

to:

```
create view v_users as
     select u.user_id
     from users u join
          user_addresses ua
          on ua.user_id = u.user_id and
             current_timestamp >= ua.eff_ts and
             (current_timestamp < ua.end_ts or ua.end_ts is null);
```

Voila!  Nothing breaks downstream.

Comment: hello, creating a 'v_users' table for generating a view doesn't cost storage 
Considering there are N number records(real-time)
and
Does in real-time all views created are referencing duplicate tables rather than original tables considering the situations like, the above example you given or security etc ?

Comment: @pk1618 . . . A regular view (i.e. non-materialized) does not occupy any table storage.  I don't know what you mean by "duplicate" tables, but views can also be very important for implementing security as well, because you can give users access to the views but not the underlying tables.